# expo: how can I track user interaction inside my application without relaying on third party dashboards

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics, analysis

I have applications deployed on Play Store, and I want to track users' interactions with the applications so I can make the application more user-friendly

things I need to keep track of:

- **screen time**: How much time a user spends on each screen.
- **clicks**: the user clicks.
- **must-clicked product**: I need to see the must-click products so I can make users easy to reach them

all this without relying on third-party dashboards, cuz I have the backend, I only need a way or package (to make it easier) to collect user's data and send it to my back end.

I search all the available packages but I found the same problem. I need to go to their dashboard if I want to take a look at the collected data

NOTE:

> I want something to connect directly to the back end without the need to export data and then reupload it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Google Analytics for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics), then export the data to your own backend if you'd rather not use the Firebase console's UI for reporting.

Comment: I want something to connect directly to the back end without the need to export data and then reupload it.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I track user interaction inside my application without relying on third-party dashboards?

If you're using Firebase, please note that [Google Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics) is a Firebase product and **not** a third-party service. You can either use the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) to track user interaction or as @GregFenton recommended, you can export the data and do whatever you want with it.

**Edit:**

According to your last comment, I understand that you're looking for [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) which:

> Provides programmatic methods to access report data in Google Analytics

Comment: I want something to connect directly to the back end without the need to export data and then reupload it.

Comment: I see. Please see my updated answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: it looks good but my back end has to fetch data from the google analytics API and that's not ideal for me, I want somehow to post the collected data directly to my back end without relaying on another API

Comment: the point is I want something to collect user interacts and when the user closes the app the collected data is then submitted to my back end without any third-party API

Comment: In that case, you should create your own mechanism. I'm not aware of something that collects data in the way you say. You need a custom solution based on your needs.

Comment: thank you for your help so far, but if you have any idea on how can i implement my solution would be greate

Comment: StackOverflow is a place for solving code-related problems. If you want an idea for such a use case you should consider using Reddit.

Comment: Did my answer and updated answer help? Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?